# Symfony 2 Crawler form submission shows error "LogicException: Unable to submit on a "input" tag."

Tags: symfony, phpunit, functional-testing

Let's say, I have a form:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="myinput" value="3" />
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is my filtering and testing with Crawler:

```
$client = static::createClient();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'test.php');

$filter = 'button';
$buttonNode = $crawler->selectButton($crawler->filter($filter));
$this->assertEquals(1, $buttonNode->count()); // this works

$form = $buttonNode->form(); // This shows error "LogicException: Unable to submit on a "input" tag."
$client->submit($form);
```

Comment: I couldn't get the symfony2 testclient to submit a form without an submit button. You either use something like selenium, sahi or zombie.js for this tests or add a input submit button which you then hide with css.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem will be in the definition of the button. I will rename it just for the sake of better understanding and add the type there:

`<button type="submit">SubmitLabel</button>`

Then it should work like this I think:

```
$client = static::createClient();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'test.php');

$buttonCrawlerNode = $crawler->selectButton('SubmitLabel');      
$form = $buttonCrawlerNode->form();
$client->submit($form);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a way like my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935683/how-to-add-xml-content-to-form-in-symfony).

Or it's just for one test and not many test you can use [casperJS](http://casperjs.org/)