# How to add XML Content to form in Symfony

Tags: symfony, functional-testing, web-crawler

I don't find a way to add "button" or "input" fields to a form to the crawler in Symfony for testing.
I'm doing this :

```
$crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '');
$document = new \DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml('<button type="submit" name="_submit" href="#">Create</button >');
$nodeList = $document->getElementsByTagName('button');
$node = $document->getElementsByTagName('button')->item(0);
$crawler->addNode($node, $form);
var_dump($crawler->filter('button[name="_submit"]')->text()); //Return Create Logic
```

But when i try to send my form i've got :

```
$form = $crawler->selectButton('_submit')->form(array(
                                                'login-input' => 'XXXXXX',
                                                'pass-input'  => 'XXXXX',
                                            ));
```

This doesn't work i've got :

> LogicException: The selected node does not have a form ancestor.

I don't have any button or input fields because it's a javascript submit.
Someone have any idea ?

---

EDIT

---

I've found an another way:
I send directly ajax request, and i've got the same effect
@redbirdo, your solution doesn't work for me, and isn't what i want at the start of my question

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate a POST request in a test using the client like this:

```
$client->request(
    'POST',
    '/submit',
    array('name' => 'Fabien'),
    array('photo' => $photo)
);
```

There are more examples under [Working with the Test Client](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#working-with-the-test-client) in the Testing section of the Symfony manual.

EDIT:

The second parameter should be the relative or absolute url of the page being tested. The '/submit' here is just a symfony example.

Comment: I've tried this :
'$this->client->request('POST', '/submit', array('login-input' => 'XXXXX', 'pass-input' => 'XxXX'));' but doesn't work, i've got an 404 error page